# achartengine pie chart not rendered in scrollview

Tags: java, android, scrollview, achartengine

I have problems displaying a `pie chart` created by `achartengine`.

My Layout XML:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#000000"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".StatisticActivity" >

    <bc.qz.client.android.custom.view.RoundRectTransparentPanel
        android:id="@+id/statisticTransparentPanel"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_margin="20dip"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="10dip" >

        <ScrollView
            android:id="@+id/statisticPageTransparentPanelScrollView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fillViewport="true" >
            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/chart"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical" >
            </LinearLayout>
        </ScrollView>
    </bc.qz.client.android.custom.view.RoundRectTransparentPanel>
</RelativeLayout>
```

My Activity:

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    LinearLayout layout=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.chart);
    mRenderer.setApplyBackgroundColor(true);
    mRenderer.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
    mRenderer.setChartTitleTextSize(20);
    mRenderer.setLabelsTextSize(15);
    mRenderer.setLabelsColor(Color.BLACK);
    mRenderer.setLegendTextSize(15);
    mRenderer.setShowLegend(false);
    mRenderer.setMargins(new int[] { 20, 30, 15, 0 });
    mRenderer.setZoomButtonsVisible(false);
    mRenderer.setStartAngle(90);
    mRenderer.setInScroll(true);
    fillPieChart();
    if (mChartView == null) {
        mChartView = ChartFactory.getPieChartView(this, mSeries, mRenderer);
        mRenderer.setClickEnabled(true);
        mRenderer.setSelectableBuffer(10);
        layout.addView(mChartView);
    } else {
        mChartView.repaint();
    }
}

public void fillPieChart() {
        for (int i = 0; i < pieChartValues.length; i++) {
            mSeries.add(" Share Holder " + (mSeries.getItemCount() + 1),
                    pieChartValues[i]);
            SimpleSeriesRenderer renderer = new SimpleSeriesRenderer();
            renderer.setColor(COLORS[(mSeries.getItemCount() - 1)
                    % COLORS.length]);
            mRenderer.addSeriesRenderer(renderer);
            if (mChartView != null)
                mChartView.repaint();
        }
    }
```

There is no exception, there is no log message but all objects are created correctly. What I get is this:

[image]

the `chart` is not displayed in my `scrollview`.

Could anybody give me a hint?

Thx
Stefan

Comment: Use HierarchyViewer to figure out what is going on http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-ui.html#HierarchyViewer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer in another question.

I changed this line

```
layout.addView(mChartView);
```

to this

```
layout.addView(mChartView, new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 500));
```

and now it works...